# Changing screen brightness before terminating

Tags: ios

I have an iOS 5.0 application for which I would like to change the screen brightness just before it terminates. I used:

```
[[UIScreen mainScreen] setBrightness:0.2];
```

I only have one view. I tried running this in `applicationWillTerminate`, `viewDidUnload`, `viewWillUnload`, `viewWillDisappear`. I used breakpoints to confirm that the code does indeed get executed, but the screen brightness doesn't change.

What am I doing wrong?

The reason for doing this is that I changed the brightness inside the application and I would like to restore the brightness to what it was before starting the application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like this might be a bug: 
https://devforums.apple.com/message/625119

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you'll not always be able to catch the application termination. In fact, you'll be able to do it only by using `UIApplicationExitOnSuspend` at `info.plist` which will disable background mode for the app and `applicationWillTerminate` will be called every time Home button is pressed. If you want, and you probably do, to support the background mode, the workaround is to restore the system-level brightness at `applicationWillResignActive` and app-level at `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Comment: @Radu You are right, also tried background thread at `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationWillTerminate ` with `UIApplicationExitOnSuspend` - nothing worked. It might be designed limitation as `applicationWillResignActive` and `applicationWillTerminate` seem for me to be called when the app is not longer displayed, so might have not enough privilege to control the UIScreen. Thanks for editing :)

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but as I think about it, it doesn't make much sense... It would make sense to not allow you to set the brightness *after* the application entered background. Plus, I think it should change the brightness back itself automatically, rather than let the application do whatever it pleases with the device brightness... This is in the user's best interest...

Comment: It definitely should not change the brightness automatically back. I use a brightness slider app all the time and i would hate it if this stopped working.